# Can't stop service in Vesta Control Panel

Tags: web-services, control-panel

### **Hi everyone**

I have a problem.

1. I stopped service named, exim and dovecot, but after a period of time, these services auto started again. Until now, I don't know why this happen even though, I was tried search for this issue but can't find out anything. please help me how to solve this problem..

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What's your OS? VestaCP version? How did you stopped them? Through interface or ssh? When they autostarted? What have you done?

Comment: os: centos 6.5, Lasted update in Vesta website, Stop by interface, When serivce start I folow by ssh, so i stop throught ssh , the day after I had been stopped service, Service auto start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it just about when you create web domain, but have check the option DNS support and mail support. So, vesta will start service named and dovecot. you just ceate a cronjob with these command:

sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-stop-service dovecot
sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-stop-service named
sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-stop-service exim

or, in the server, add these command line

JOB='8' MIN='0' HOUR='*/6' DAY='*' MONTH='*' WDAY='*' CMD='sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-stop-service exim' SUSPENDED='no' TIME='12:32:31' DATE='2014-05-22'
JOB='9' MIN='0' HOUR='*/6' DAY='*' MONTH='*' WDAY='*' CMD='sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-stop-service named' SUSPENDED='no' TIME='12:32:05' DATE='2014-05-22'
JOB='10' MIN='0' HOUR='*/6' DAY='*' MONTH='*' WDAY='*' CMD='sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-stop-service dovecot' SUSPENDED='no' TIME='12:31:50' DATE='2014-05-22'

if you have any issue, give me message :)

Comment: Scheduling a cron job to stop the services he doesn't need is not a  solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

Login as root on your server and force-stop the services:

service named stop

service exim stop

service dovecot stop

Next is to configure VestaCP to not start the services when the server is beeing rebooted:

chkconfig named off

chkconfig exim off

chkconfig dovecot off

And you're done. You can check by rebooting the server. You can also do this with other services:
clamd, spamassasin (if you installed the high ram VestaCP version and don't need the mail services)_
httpd, nginx, mysqld and vsftpd (for if you make a dns-only server)

You get the point, hope this works. Good luck